# How to number basecalls on chromatogram?

Tags: java, swing, biojava

I've created an image of a chromatogram (of a dna sequence).

How would I go about putting a number over each basecall?

I can get the pixel length of the picture and the number of bases. If I divide these, I would get the average distance between basecalls, which would offer a good approximation of where each basecall would go.

How would I put numbers (1 - [number of bases]) along the top of the picture?

Here is a picture of the GUI and what the program looks like:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5nGPfKaY21KVFVsaE9XSHJmWG8/view?usp=sharing

Here is the source code:

[When the getChrom button is pressed, the method renderTrace is executed, rendering the trace.]

```
public class TraceRender extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public TraceRender() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    fileChooser = new javax.swing.JFileChooser();
    textarea = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    getChrom = new javax.swing.JButton();
    ScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    Label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    text = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    Menu = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    File = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    Open = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    Exit = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    Edit = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    Documentation = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    Help = new javax.swing.JMenu();

    fileChooser.setDialogTitle("This is my open dialog");
    fileChooser.setFileFilter(new myCustomFilter());

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    textarea.setEditable(false);
    textarea.setText("ABSOLUTE PATH");

    getChrom.setText("Execute");
    getChrom.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            getChromActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    Label.setText("[AVI]-Error.noImageLoaded");
    ScrollPane.setViewportView(Label);

    text.setText("nothing");

    File.setText("FILE");

    Open.setText("Get File");
    Open.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            OpenActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    File.add(Open);

    Exit.setText("Close Program");
    Exit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            ExitActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    File.add(Exit);

    Menu.add(File);

    Edit.setText("EDIT");
    Menu.add(Edit);

    Documentation.setText("DOCUMENTATION");
    Menu.add(Documentation);

    Help.setText("HELP");
    Menu.add(Help);

    setJMenuBar(Menu);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(textarea, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 1005, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 79, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(getChrom, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 291, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(49, 49, 49))
        .addComponent(ScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(33, 33, 33)
            .addComponent(text, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 630, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(textarea, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(getChrom))
            .addGap(48, 48, 48)
            .addComponent(ScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 265, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(53, 53, 53)
            .addComponent(text, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(113, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void OpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        textarea.setText(String.valueOf(file.getAbsolutePath()));
    } else {
        System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
    }

}                                    

private void ExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    System.exit(0);
}                                    

private void getChromActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        renderTrace();
    } catch (IOException | UnsupportedChromatogramFormatException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TraceRender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}                                        

private void renderTrace() throws IOException, UnsupportedChromatogramFormatException {
    ABIFChromatogram abiChrom = new ABIFChromatogram();

    File abi = new File(textarea.getText());

    ABITrace abiTrace = new ABITrace(abi);
    ABIFParser abiParse = new ABIFParser(abi);
    ChromatogramFactory chromFactory = new ChromatogramFactory();

    Chromatogram chrom = ChromatogramFactory.create(abi);

    ChromatogramGraphic gfx = new ChromatogramGraphic(chrom);

    gfx.setHeight(240);
    gfx.setHorizontalScale(2.0f);
    // set some options that affect the output
    // turn off filled-in "callboxes"
    gfx.setOption(ChromatogramGraphic.Option.DRAW_CALL_A,
            Boolean.FALSE);
    gfx.setOption(ChromatogramGraphic.Option.DRAW_CALL_C,
            Boolean.FALSE);
    gfx.setOption(ChromatogramGraphic.Option.DRAW_CALL_G,
            Boolean.FALSE);
    gfx.setOption(ChromatogramGraphic.Option.DRAW_CALL_T,
            Boolean.FALSE);
    gfx.setOption(ChromatogramGraphic.Option.DRAW_CALL_OTHER,
            Boolean.TRUE);
    gfx.setOption(ChromatogramGraphic.Option.DRAW_CALL_SEPARATORS,
            Boolean.TRUE);

    // this option controls whether each trace/callbox/etc is scaled/positioned
    // individually, or whether the scaling is done on all shapes at the level
    // of the graphics context
    // enabling this option is recommended for higher-quality output

    gfx.setOption(ChromatogramGraphic.Option.USE_PER_SHAPE_TRANSFORM,
            Boolean.TRUE);

    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
            gfx.getWidth(),
            gfx.getHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
    g2.setBackground(Color.white);
    g2.clearRect(0, 0, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight());
    if (g2.getClip() == null) {
        g2.setClip(new Rectangle(0, 0, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight()));
    }
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    // the main event
    gfx.drawTo(g2);
    // work-around an OS X bug where sometimes the last Shape drawn
    // doesn't show up in the output
    g2.draw(new java.awt.Rectangle(-10, -10, 5, 5));

    text.setText(String.valueOf(gfx.getWidth()));
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(bi);
    Label.setIcon(ii);
    /*
    try {
        ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new File("gfx-image.png"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    */


}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TraceRender.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TraceRender.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TraceRender.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TraceRender.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new TraceRender().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

class myCustomFilter extends javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        // Allow only directories, or files with ".txt" extension
        return file.isDirectory() || file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".ab1");
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        // This description will be displayed in the dialog,
        // hard-coded = ugly, should be done via I18N
        return "ABIF Files (*.ab1)";
    }
}


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JMenu Documentation;
private javax.swing.JMenu Edit;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem Exit;
private javax.swing.JMenu File;
private javax.swing.JMenu Help;
private javax.swing.JLabel Label;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar Menu;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem Open;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane ScrollPane;
private javax.swing.JFileChooser fileChooser;
private javax.swing.JButton getChrom;
private javax.swing.JTextField text;
private javax.swing.JTextField textarea;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Please consider posting a [mcve] which is runnable for everyone. With what exactly are you having problems with? Since you know how to calculate the x coordinates, you could try to just `drawString`s representing the corresponding number onto the top of the canvas.

Comment: @LuxxMiner I can't post a full runnable example because I use 9 other jar files from biojava, and the program needs to read from an ABIF chromatogram. My problem is coming up with the syntax of a loop that will do this for me. I want it to add a number at every given interval, where the interval is (width/sequenceLength) pixels long, and each number is one greater than the last. Basically, putting a number over each basecall. All of the source code is above though, and a picture of what the program looks like too.

Comment: Maybe something like `int counter = 0;for (int i = interval / 2; i < sequenceLength * interval; i += interval) {String str = String.valueOf(++counter);g.drawString(String.valueOf(str), i - g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(str) / 2,g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());}`? Btw, I don't think your problem has anything to do with the Chromotogram itself, you'd just need a `JPanel` and any Integer which represents the sequence length for a MCVE.

Comment: @LuxxMiner I used some of the code you have, and it appears to have worked. I can't confirm because what I'm seeing is very faint, but it appears that I do have numbers. Their font color, though, is white. I know this may sound silly, but how would I change them to black?

Comment: Put `g.setColor(Color.BLACK);` before the for-loop.

Comment: @LuxxMiner The numbers turned out to be very imprecise, but now I have a method that returns the rectuangular dimensions of each basecall callbox. The x location of each callbox is the x location of the previous callbox + the width of the previous callbox. Using the method: gfx.getCallboxBounds(integer).getX() I can get the x value of the basecall. How would I restructure the loop to give precise locations for the numbers? (If you know how to restructure the loop, you can put it as an answer, and if it works, I'll choose it.) EDIT (Also, so the loop only should show every tenth base number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my testings, this worked (assuming that the integer argument that `getCallboxBounds()` takes is the index, not the number to be displayed):

```
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
for (int i = 9; i < sequenceLength; i += 10) {
    String str = String.valueOf(i + 1);
    g.drawString(str,
            getCallboxBounds(i).getX()
                    + (getCallboxBounds(i).getWidth() - g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(str)) / 2,
            g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
}
```

If you want to display every number (not just the ones where `% 10 == 0`), then change

```
for (int i = 9; i < sequenceLength; i += 10) {
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < sequenceLength; i++) {
```

I hope it also works for you.